# How to compile this rust code using GATs?

Tags: rust, generic-associated-types

I wrote the rust code using generic associated types like below:

```
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]

pub trait Foo {
    type Arg<N: Clone>;
    fn foo<N: Clone>(arg: Self::Arg<N>) {
        println!("hello");
    }
}

pub fn call_foo<N: Clone, F: Foo<Arg<N> = N>>() {
    // I want to create this Box value here
    let a = Box::new(1);
    F::foo(a);
}
```

This code causes the following compilation error:

```text
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> core/src/utils.rs:33:5
   |
33 |     F::foo(a);
   |     ^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `N` declared on the associated function `foo`
   |
   = note: cannot satisfy `_: Clone`
note: required by a bound in `Foo::foo`
  --> core/src/utils.rs:26:15
   |
26 |     fn foo<N: Clone>(arg: Self::Arg<N>) {
   |               ^^^^^ required by this bound in `Foo::foo`
help: consider specifying the type argument in the function call
   |
33 |     F::foo::<N>(a);
   |           +++++
```

And when I fix the code following the help message, I got another error:

```text
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> core/src/utils.rs:33:17
   |
31 | pub fn call_foo<N: Clone, F: Foo<Arg<N> = N>>() {
   |                 - this type parameter
32 |     let a = Box::new(1);
33 |     F::foo::<N>(a);
   |     ----------- ^ expected type parameter `N`, found struct `Box`
   |     |
   |     arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `N`
                      found struct `Box<{integer}>`
note: associated function defined here
  --> core/src/utils.rs:26:8
   |
26 |     fn foo<N: Clone>(arg: Self::Arg<N>) {
   |        ^^^           -----------------
```

`F::foo::<Box<usize>>(a)` also causes the same error `error[E0308]: mismatched types` .

Can I compile this code?

Comment: As the error suggests, `F::foo()` requires an argument of type `F::Arg<N>`, which you have specified as `Arg<N> = N`. However, you attempt to pass a value of type `Box<i32>` instead of the generic type `N` (which can be arbitrarily specified by the caller of `call_foo`). Perhaps you wanted the constraint `F: Foo<Arg<N> = Box<i32>>` instead? Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I also think this is confusing since you have two separate uses of `N` in `call_foo`'s signature; I would definitely suggest using different names to make it clearer what's what, I'm honestly a bit confused what the signature is supposed to mean.

Comment: @Coder-256 Thank you for your answer and advice. The constraint `F: Foo<Arg<N> = Box<i32>>` didn't work, but `F: Foo<Arg<Box<usize>> = Box<usize>>` worked. I misunderstood that I can't specify a concrete type to GATs constraints.

Comment: Note that issues about confusing GATs error messages, and this problem in particular, were issued in the [GAT stabilization PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/96709), specifically [this (long) comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/96709#issuecomment-1126690737). Overall, many people (myself included) feel that GATs are not ready for stabilization, if we should stabilize them at all.

Comment: Great, and you’re right: my mistake, the constraint I suggested was actually incorrect. However, I still worry that something is mixed up here. What is `N` and why do you need it?

Comment: @Coder-256 Your constraint could work, but you need to specify the types explicitly: `F::foo::<N>(a)`.

Comment: "Can I compile this code?" - this question is meaningless. No, obviously you cannot compile this code, the compiler is giving you an error when trying. You may meant to ask "can I do what I want here", but for us to be able to answer that we need to know what you want to do.